# How to remove element from DOM tree with the event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is the element which I want to remove:

```
<div id="tobeRemoved">
    <div class="eventAttached"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="eventAttached"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And its child may be have event attached.

And now I want to remove it from the DOM tree; I know I can use this:

```
var ele=document.getElementById("tobeRemoved");
ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
```

But how about the events? Are they cleared at the same time auto?

BTW, I prefer to a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Yes div class eventAttached will also be removed since the element is a child of tobeRemoved class

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala Yes, but they are asking if any events attached to these divs will be removed automatically

Comment: logically it will be removed since the div class eventAttached was removed. so any events attached on that class will also be removed if all class eventAttached was removed.

Comment: Attached handlers are known to clog up the garbage collector. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're developing a framework or suffering performance issues though.

Comment: yes,ianpgall is right.I wonder if the event handler can also be removed autoly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if you know the event type:

```
function removeEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
 if (elem.removeEventListener) 
    elem.removeEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 if (elem.detachEvent)
    elem.detachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}
```

or jQuery's [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function.

Answer (score 0):

If the events are added with jQuery it will remove the events when the elements are removed.